# Values inputed in modal does not fire on change event in document js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal that is inside a td tag.

Once the user has selected the desired colours and closed the modal, it should effect the pricing.

The pricing is effected by the number of colours you select.

If you open the modal and select, for example, 2 colours and close it. It does not fire the on change event.

To trigger the event you have to change either the width or drop input again.

I'm not sure how to trigger the change.

Please help!

Here is what I have:

Html:

```
<tr>

  <td>
    <input type="text" name="width[]" class="width">
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="text" name="drop[]" class="drop">
  </td>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="features btn btn- 
   primary" data-toggle="modal" data- target=".featuresModal">Features
    </button>

    <!--modal -->
    <div class="featuresModal modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="featuresModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content text-center">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-centre">
              <select data-placeholder="Colours" class="colours 
   chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4" name="colours[]">" +
                <option value=\ "\"></option>
                getMultiColours() +
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="trigger btn btn- 
   secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Save and Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

js:

```
$(document).on('change', '.colours, .width, .drop', function () {
    var width = $(".width", $(this).parent().parent()).val();
    var drop = $(".drop", $(this).parent().parent()).val();
    var sub_total = $(".total",$(this).parent().parent());
    var colours = $(".colours",$(this).parent().parent()).val();
    var colour_count = colours.length;

    $.ajax({
        url: "#",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            "product": product,
            "width": width,
            "drop": drop
        },
        success: function (data) {
            data = parseInt(data);

            if (data === "") {
                parent = sub_total.val(0);
            }
            else {
                var price = 0;
                if (colour_count <= 1) {
                    parent =
                        sub_total.val(data);
                }
                else if (colour_count <= 2) {
                    data = data + (data * 0.15);
                    parent =
                        sub_total.val(data);
                }
                else {
                    data = data + (data * 0.15);
                    for (i = 2; i <
                        colour_count; i++) {
                        data += (data * 0.10);
                    }
                    parent = sub_total.val(data);
                }
            }
            calculate(parent)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try on focus instead

Comment: Did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workable solution.

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.featuresModal', function() 
  {
    get pricing...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The change event is not fired after changing the value in javascript. You have to call trigger. For example, to trigger change event for variable sub_total:

```
sub_total.val(data).trigger('change');
```